# leaderboard example not run when change folder structure

Tags: javascript, meteor

this time i learn meteor.js :D
i learn from example.
example that i use now is leaderboard :http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard
from native example project I have this folder structure :

```
leaderboard
|-.meteor
|-leaderboard.css
|-leaderboard.html
|-leaderboard.js
```

I try to understand meteor.js folder sturcture now, i try to move to be like this :

```
leaderboard
|-.meteor
|-client
    |--leaderboard.css
    |-leaderboard.html
    |-leaderboard.js
|-public
|-server
```

I didnt change any code, just create folder and move
And after that i start meteor and access localhost:3000
but web didnt work.
help me how to solve this problem and please exlpain me how to use private folder :D

thanks

update 
I try follow instruction.
I update my server folder with leadership.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["Ada Lovelace",
                   "Grace Hopper",
                   "Marie Curie",
                   "Carl Friedrich Gauss",
                   "Nikola Tesla",
                   "Claude Shannon"];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        Players.insert({name: names[i], score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5});
    }
  });
```

and my leaderboard.js in `/client`  i update too with no if(Meteor.isClient)
this is my error :

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

W2036-17:49:01.658(7)? (STDERR) D:\Meteor\leaderboard\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:195
W2036-17:49:01.661(7)? (STDERR) }).run();
W2036-17:49:01.662(7)? (STDERR)    ^
W2036-17:49:01.663(7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Players is not defined
W2036-17:49:01.665(7)? (STDERR)     at app/server/leadership.js:2:9
W2036-17:49:01.666(7)? (STDERR)     at D:\Meteor\leaderboard\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:168:61
W2036-17:49:01.668(7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W2036-17:49:01.669(7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\yoza\AppData\Local\.meteor\tools\e42f0b78d3\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W2036-17:49:01.671(7)? (STDERR)     at D:\Meteor\leaderboard\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:168:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is code in `leadership.js` which needs to be placed in the `/server` folder in a `.js` file too.

All the code inside `if(Meteor.isClient){` is meant to run on the client only. So that should go in the `/client` folder. It doesn't need the `if(Meteor.isClient){` condition check when it is in the client folder.

Likewise stuff which is in `if(Meteor.isServer) {` belongs in the `/server` folder.

It doesn't work because the files in `/client` only get run on the client side and there are server side parts like the collections which need to be run on the server.

Comment: You also have to copy over the top line which is something like `Players = new Meteor.Collection('players')` you will notice in leadership.js it is not in the `isServer` or `isClient` blocks because its shared on both